# Handling multiple views controllers in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

I am new to CodeIgniter 4.

```
I have one controller named Pages and helps to display website pages normally. Then I have another controller named Admin which is suppose to load the admin view with its own header and footer files.
```

While Pages controller works fine, the Admin controller keeps saying 404-file not found admin.

I think I have a problem with my current Route settings below. Please help.

```
$routes->setDefaultController('Pages');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('default');

// Route Definitions

$routes->get('/', 'Pages::index');
$routes->get('(:any)', 'Pages::default/$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

try ajusting your code like this.

```
$routes->setDefaultController('Pages');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('default');
```

// Route Definitions

```
$routes->resource('pages');
$routes->get('/', 'Pages::index');
$routes->get('(:any)', 'Pages::default/$1');
```

Comment: Thanks brother @cyrusien-kamgue, below is the final route settings and it worked

`$routes->resource('pages');`
$routes->resource('admin');
`$routes->get('/', 'Pages::index');`
`$routes->get('/', 'Admin::index');`
`$routes->get('(:any)', 'Pages::default/$1');`
`$routes->get('(:any)', 'Admin::default/$1');`